# How to align an image side by side with a heading element?

Tags: html, css

below is my code:

```
<div><img src="images/ConfigIcon.png"/><h1>System Configuration</h1></div>
```

I want to make the image appear beside my h1 header. But what I get is that the image is always at top of my header. Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to have to post your CSS

Comment: Here's a great overview explaining css `display`.  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`<h1>` is a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), and browsers typically display the block-level element with a newline both before and after the element. However you can make it as `inline` or `inline-block`

```css
h1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="images/ConfigIcon.png"/><h1>System Configuration</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

There are soooo many ways to do this.

Some of these methods are *really* gross and should be avoided, but I thought it would be interesting to list them out for the sake of illustration.

**Use the `align` property on the `<img>`.**

```
<div><img src="images/ConfigIcon.png" align="left"/><h1>System Configuration</h1></div>
```

**Nest the `<img>` inside the `<h1>`.**

```
<div>
  <h1><img src="images/ConfigIcon.png" /> System Configuration</h1>
</div>
```

**Use an inline style to `float` the `<h1>`.**

```
<div>
  <img src="images/ConfigIcon.png"/>
  <h1 style="float: right">System Configuration</h1>
</div>
```

**Use an inline style to `float` the `<img>`.**

```
<div>
  <img src="images/ConfigIcon.png" style="float: left"/>
  <h1>System Configuration</h1>
</div>
```

**Use inline styles to make both `<img>` and `<h1>` display as `inline` elements.**

```
<div>
  <img src="images/ConfigIcon.png" style="display: inline" />
  <h1 style="display: inline">System Configuration</h1>
</div>
```

**Use inline styles to make both `<img>` and `<h1>` display as `inline-block` elements.**

```
<div>
  <img src="images/ConfigIcon.png" style="display: inline-block" />
  <h1 style="display: inline-block">System Configuration</h1>
</div>
```

**Use css background-image property and some padding.**

The following example assumes you have a 16x16 px icon image.

```
<div>
  <h1 style="background: url(images/ConfigIcon.png) 0 50% no-repeat;padding-left: 16px">System Configuration</h1>
</div>
```

And many more...

Comment: Thanks for this, it has solved one of my issues: sizing and aligning an `i` Font Awesome element with a `h1`: putting the `i` inside the `h1`was the solution. :)